# Array in socket Programming

Tags: java, sockets, structure

I am writing a client-server program using socket programming in Java. I need to send multiple values to the server. Can I store this value in a structure object and send the structure object to the server?

Comment: If you [serialize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) it properly.

Comment: Serialization is indeed the answer. But study it carefully, it's better to do it properly, and there are some pitfalls. Good no-cost material for that: google "effective java pdf Joshua Bloch" and read chapter about serialization (or the whole book).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`ObjectOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) and [`ObjectInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html). You can send any Object that implements the [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface (also note that any Objects within the Object has to implement it as well). To for instance send an array of SomeObject and then SomeOtherObject:

For instance, to send an array of `SomeObject` and `SomeOtherObject`:

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
oos.writeObject(new SomeObject[]{new SomeObject(), new SomeObject()});
oos.writeObject(new SomeOtherObject());
```

To read them:

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
SomeObject[] obj = (SomeObject[]) ois.readObject();
SomeOtherObject someOtherObj = (SomeOtherObject) ois.readObject();
```

Note:

Comment: Or just write and then read the two objects separately. There's no actual need for the array.

Comment: @EJP in the title there's "Array", so I figured that's what was wanted, but you're right of course.